# Java: Simply convert a decimal byte to a hexadecimal byte

Tags: java, hex, byte, decimal

I want to get this:

```
byte dec = 10;
```

to this:

```
byte hex = 0x0A;
```

But I can't find the solution anywhere.
I see always `String s = Integer.parseInt(...`
But I don't want a `String` as result.
I want a `byte`.

Comment: I think I got the solution: `byte hex = 0x00; for(byte i=1; i<dec+1; i++) {++hex}`

Comment: There's no such thing as a "decimal byte" or a "hex byte". It's just a number. You can use `byte hex = dec;` and it will give exactly the same result as your loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *byte* is just a sequence of bits in memory -- it doesn't matter how it's represented visually, and two different representations can mean the same thing. If all you want is a *hex literal*, you can try this:

```
byte dec = 10;
byte hex = 0xA;  // hex literal

System.out.println(dec == hex);
```

```
true
```

Note that `dec` and `hex` are exactly identical here; `10` and `0xA` represent the same number, just in different bases.

If you want to display a byte in hex, you can use [`Integer.toHexString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29):

```
byte dec = 10;
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(dec));
```

```
a
```

Comment: @KeksArmee I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to display a byte in a hexadecimal format?

Comment: you said that there is no hexa/dec byte in java. at first i wanted to store it in hex, since that is not possible i have to display it in hex as a string. so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not get "A" as a byte. Bytes are an extension of numbers, so you can only hold numeric values here. What you may wish to do is to return a char that represents the hex, or a String.

Something like this might be of use:

```
package sandbox;

public class Sandbox
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte value = 1;
        char charValue = getHex(value);
        System.out.println(charValue);

    }

    private static char getHex(byte b)
    {
        Byte bObj = new Byte(b);
        if (b < 10) { return bObj.toString().charAt(0); }
        else
        {
            char hexChar = (char)(bObj.toString().charAt(1) + 'A' - '0');
            return hexChar;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope i have been helpful.

Comment: He likely means "A" in the hexadecimal system, which is 10 in decimal.

Comment: I agree. However, since these are the same in a byte primitive, i am providing for any other possible interpretation. Perhaps the O.P. wished to represent the byte as 'A'.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 0x0A instead of A

Comment: Fair enough. Then, as arshajii says, these two values are the same, and entering "0x0A" as a value for a byte is just there for convenience. Java understands this as an integer with value "10". :)